# How to show select list selection in the middle?

Tags: javascript, list, selection

I need to know, if it's possible to vertically center a selected item of a select list (with javascript):

[image]

#### My approaches

First, I tried to select the item and then just scroll the list. But this isn't possible as I found out via google. The only way to change the vertical scroll is to select an item.

So the second approach was to select an item which has an index plus 3. So the list would scroll down to this item. After that, I selected the "real" index.
But it doesn't work, because the item will always been selected at the bottom.

#### Question

And now I'm here and would like to ask, if it's possible to get the selected list item into the middle of the list?

And how it would be done ;)

Regards Florian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a drop-down list is browser-handled and can't be manipulated very well, you have to recreate the behavior of a drop-down list yourself.

Nested divs should work with `overflow: scroll;`.

Then, you can use any scrollTo solution javascript has.

Comment: The problem here is, that I have a list of 5000 items. If I would list them all in a div, the browser would be killed (especially IE). How would you solve this?

Comment: I don't see how the `option` tags are any lighter than `div`. You can use `span` too, but I don't think it'd change much. A solution would be to ajax-load/remove new elements while the user is scrolling the list.